# Python request POST (and Cookie) to login and after GET to scrape failed

Tags: python, python-requests, http-post, session-cookies, http-get

I am trying to scrape data results (odds as per betfair starting price) of horse racing from site 'https://www.timeform.com/', but it seems that I am not logging well (my POST request isn't good)

Any suggestions/proposals?

My code:

```
import requests

url_get='https://www.timeform.com/horse-racing/result/brighton/2018-06-11/0200/6/1/phoenix-arts-club-fillies-handicap'
url_post_pgin='https://www.timeform.com/horse-racing/account/handlelogin?returnUrl=%2Fhorse-racing%2F'
payload = {"EmailAddress":"mymail@gmail.com","Password":"XXXXXXXXX","RememberMe":"true"}

headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Connection':'keep-alive',
'Content-Length':'195',
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'DNT':1,
'Host':'www.timeform.com',
'Referer':'https://www.timeform.com/horse-racing/account/sign-in?returnUrl=%2Fhorse-racing%2F',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':1,
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}

s = requests.session()
login = s.post(url=url_post_pgin,headers=headers, data=payload) #this should log me in, but I am afraid is not doing good job
get_data=s.get(url=url_get,headers=headers, cookies=s.cookies)

#file = open("rr.html", "w")
#file.write(str(m.text))
#file.close()
```

*EDIT: I changed url name variables.

Comment: I tried to run the script and it appears `get_data` is running in an endless loop, do you have the same problem?

Comment: Try to remove headers and it will give 200 OK response, but 'non logged' html code will be loaded

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I just posted my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

taking a closer look at the website and your code it appears that the problem occurs due to your header, the way you are sending one of your requests, and a post request that you aren't sending.

## Problem 1: Header

as we can see your header is fairly big. Even though a big header isn't equal to a bad header but in your case you are sending a fair amount of useless items in the header that may potentially confuse the server so I try replacing you header with the following one:

```
 headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}
```

as you see I have removed quite a few things from it.

## Problem 2: Wrong way of sending a request (in your case):

The whole goal of `requests.session()` is to keep track of all the cookies and prevent you from manually injecting them into each of your requests. thus you should change this:

```
get_data=s.get(url=url_get,headers=headers, cookies=s.cookies)
```

to this:

```
get_data=s.get(url=url_get,headers=headers)
```

(The cookies will be inserted into automatically each time you use `requests.session` when sending a request)

## Problem 3: The Request That you didn't send as noted before your problem occurs because you forgot to send a post request. I won't go into details on this but the request you are missing is this one:

```
s.get(url='https://www.timeform.com/horse-racing/account/sign-in', headers=headers)
```

---

All in all, after all these changes your code should look something like this:

```
import requests

url_get='https://www.timeform.com/horse-racing/result/brighton/2018-06-11/0200/6/1/phoenix-arts-club-fillies-handicap'
url_post_pgin='https://www.timeform.com/horse-racing/account/handlelogin?returnUrl=%2Fhorse-racing%2F'
url_post_pgin2='https://www.timeform.com/horse-racing/account/sign-in'
payload = {"EmailAddress":"mymail@gmail.com","Password":"XXXXXXXXX","RememberMe":"true"}

headers = {'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}

s = requests.session()

login = s.post(url=url_post_pgin,headers=headers, data=payload) #this should log me in, but I am afraid is not doing good job
s.get(url=url_post_pgin2,headers=headers) #this should log me in, but I am afraid is not doing good job
get_data=s.get(url=url_get,headers=headers)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my friend, still get_data.text is like logging (not logged in) didn't pass. Did you had success? BTW TNX!

Comment: try running the code again ( I just made an edit ), Well I don't have an account on the website so I can't really check :)

Comment: great, thanks you can remove them from the comment now. give me a bit of time I will try to fix the problem.

Comment: God Bless you Fozoro

Comment: Hmm seems tougher than I thought still haven't found a solution, I will leave it for now then come back to it later.

Comment: Ok, if you find something let me know my dear! BIG TNX!

Comment: sure :) I will try my best

Comment: @Fozoro did you ever find a solution to this? Also, was there any detrimental effect to your account by trying and failing to log in frequently during development?

Comment: @Jovan, are you still using this snippet to log into timeform?

I am trying to use my own credentials and the scraped html indicated that I am not logged in